# using virtual functions versus static_cast from base to derived

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to understand which implementation below is "faster". Assume that one compiles this code with and without the -DVIRTUAL flag.

I assume that compiling without -DVIRTUAL will be faster because:

a] There is no vtable used

b] The compiler might be able to optimize the assembly instructions because it "knows" exactly which call will be made given the various options (there are only a finite number of options).

My question is PURELY related to speed, not pretty code.

a] Am I correct in my analysis above?

b] Will the branch predictor / compiler combination be intelligent enough to optimize for a given branch of the switch statement? See that the "type" is a const int.

c] Are there any other factors that I am missing?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(int t) : type(t) {}
    ~Base() {}

   const int type;
#ifdef VIRTUAL
    virtual void fn1()=0;
#else
    void fn2();
#endif
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() : Base(1) { }
    ~Derived1() {}
    void fn1() { std::cout << "in Derived1()" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2 : public  Base
{
public:
    Derived2() : Base(2) {  }
    ~Derived2() { }
    void fn1() { std::cout << "in Derived2()" << std::endl; }
};


#ifndef VIRTUAL
    void Base::fn2()
    {
        switch(type)
        {
        case 1:
            (static_cast<Derived1* const>(this))->fn1();
            break;
        case 2:
            (static_cast<Derived2* const>(this))->fn1();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        };
    }
#endif


int main()
{
    Base *test = new Derived1();
#ifdef VIRTUAL
    test->fn1();
#else
test->fn2();
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try timing it both ways? I'd be interested in the results.

Comment: Can we have a reason "Performance question without profiling" to close questions with, please?

Comment: @sbi: you don't have to answer it. Profiling is not the only way to determine performance, albeit most of the time it's the only practical way. If you think this question cannot be answered, then there's already a close reason for that, so I think it would be foolish to introduce a new reason-to-close, that might catch the odd question that is valid (e.g. questions about cycle-counting), solely to allow a more accurate snark at questions which aren't valid.

Comment: @Steve: No point in adding another answer that repeats what everybody I up-voted already said.

Comment: If you guys think that this is the only way to determine which is faster then I am happy to close. Maybe I should be more specific and talk only about Nehalum architecture since I know it probably depends on what chip is used.

Comment: @stackmate: the problem is that by the time you're asking a specific enough question for someone to actually say "yes" or "no", you could have just tested it yourself. Otherwise you'll get more or less general answers along the lines of "it depends".

Comment: @Steve: I'm not so sure, posting a code segment and asking if there's anything obvious I've missed is far easier than building a really correct test harness. If I'm testing just the compiler optimization then maybe I could just pass an int to the function and have the function return the square. I guess if the compiler was smart, it would never have to make the call and just inline the int*int instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the platform and the compiler. A `switch` statement can be implemented as a test and branch or a jump table (i.e., an indirect branch). A `virtual` function is usually implemented as an indirect branch. If your compiler turns the `switch` statement into a jump table, the two approaches differ by one additional dereference. If that is the case and this particular usage happens infrequently enough (or thrashes the cache enough) then you might see a difference due to an extra cache miss.

On the other hand, if the `switch` statement is simply a test and branch, you might see a much bigger performance difference on some in-order CPUs that flush the instruction cache on an indirect branch (or require a high latency between setting the destination of an indirect branch and jumping to it).

If you are really concerned with the overhead of virtual function dispatch, say, for an inner loop over a heterogenous collection of objects, you might want to reconsider where you perform the dynamic dispatch. It doesn't have to be per object; it could also be per known groupings of objects with the same type.

Comment: I agree with your analysis @MSN. The resulting performance difference is very small between the virtual function and switch. I am wondering more if there's anything to be said for compile time optimizations given that the finite options are known (as distinct from a virtual function)

Comment: @stackmate, not really. The optimizations you can do with a switch statement end up depending on the fact that the expression is not known at compile time. I suppose the compiler could reduce the size of the jump table if it knew the options were small enough, but at that point you should rethink how you are using dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the VTable.  The VTable is simply a jump table (In most implementations though AFAIK the spec does not guarantee this!).  In fact you could go as far as saying its a giant switch statement.  As such I'd wager the speed would be exactly the same with both your methods.

If anything I'd imagine the VTable method would be *slightly* faster as the compiler can make better decisions to optimise for cache alignment and so forth...

Answer (score 1):

Have you measured the performance to see if there's even any difference at all?

I suppose not, because then you wouldn't be asking here.  It's the only reasonable response though.

Comment: I have not measured performance, I should if that's what you all think is best. I thought maybe someone would know off-hand if I am completely off base

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to answer without specifying compiler and compiler options.

I see no particular reason why your non-virtual code should necessarily be any faster to make the call than the virtual code. In fact, the switch might well be slower than a vtable, since a call using a vtable will load an address and jump to it, whereas the switch will load an integer and do a little bit of thinking. Either one of them could be faster. For obvious reasons, a virtual call is not specified by the standard to be "slower than any other thing you invent to replace it".

I think it's reasonably unlikely that a randomly-chosen compiler will actually inline the call in the virtual case, but it's certainly allowed to (under the as-if rule), since the dynamic type of `*test` could be determined by data-flow analysis or similar. I think it's reasonably likely that with optimization enabled a randomly-chosen compiler will inline everything in the non-virtual case. But then, you've given a small example with very short functions all in one TU, so inlining is especially easy.

Comment: So the second part of your answer is really what is of most interest to me. Since the compiler knows the actual finite code paths that might be executed, it *could* do some optimizations. In the case the call is virtual, the compiler most likely won't do any optimization right?

Comment: @stackmate: If you threw every compiler in the world into a hat and picked one at random, I'd think probably not. If you have an actual compiler in mind, though, do what John says and look at the code it emits. I don't think it's a good idea to show the most interest in the parts of answers which support what you thought before you asked the question ;-)

Comment: Ha! Point taken, though I did mention the compiler in [b]. I am just using gcc4.4.5 on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not prematurely micro-optimizing pointlessly, and you have profiled your code and found this to be a problem that needs solving, the best way to figure out the answer to your question is to compile both in release with full optimizations and examine the generated machine code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily true that avoiding vtables will be faster - to be sure, you should measure yourself.

Comment: I agree, but as I assume that since the compiler is given the finite list of execution paths, the code could be optimized in each case. I could be totally off here though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- The `static_cast` version *may* introduce a branch (likely not to, if it gets optimized to a jump table),
- The `vtable` version on all implementations I know *will* result in a jump table.

See a pattern here?

Generally, you'd prefer linear time lookup, not branching the code, so the virtual function method seems to be better.